# Plane Truss- Missing Member

Tags: statics

[image]

Hello, so I'm looking for some help with part (a) of the question below. I've never seen an example like it before and I'm not sure where to start. How do I work would which is the missing member for the truss below? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to note is the fact that, without some sort of bracing within BCEF, the structure is unstable. As-is, that square is completely flexible, and can flatten completely: CE can move down-and-to-the-right, transforming the square into a parallelogram and finally into a flat pancake, with C moving down to F and E moving 2 m below F (so BC becomes the same as BF, basically).

So we will indeed need some bracing there. Part (a) of the question just asks whether that bracing should be placed at BE or CF.

Given that the only "problem" with the structure is that it lacks any bracing in BCEF, theoretically there's no difference between either choice, since they both serve to brace that part of the structure. So you're just deciding what's the best choice between two valid options.

There are two ways to think about this: what's the best layout for this specific element of the structure or what's the best layout for the entire structure. Usually, the proper way to think about it is for the entire structure. After all, if putting this brace in a way that's bad for it (that is, the piece needs to be heavier to withstand the load), but better for the entire structure, the cost-benefit is worth it: a single heavier brace to make the entire structure lighter.

In this case, however, the entire-structure view is a bit ambiguous (see below), so I'd make my decision thinking about what's best for the brace (well, for this simple exercise; in real life, I'd look at the entire-structure case more closely to see what was best).

So let's look at the problem both ways:

### What's best for the brace?

It feels beyond the scope of this question, so I won't explain why (add a comment if you're interested, in which case I'll consider an edit). But a fun fact about such bracing is that the magnitude of the load is indifferent to the direction of the brace. The only thing that changes is the direction. That is, you choose whether the brace should be under tension or compression.

And that's the answer to the problem if you look at it this way. After all, the problem states this is a steel structure. And we know that steel behaves much better under tension than compression (due to the risk of buckling under compression). So we want to put that brace under tension.

So now it's just a matter of determining which orientation will put the brace under tension. I find it quite intuitive that the answer is BE.

Basically, this is a structure under a force pointing mainly down and a bit to the left. As that force makes its way "up the truss", it will get to BCEF as a series of internal forces, but the resultant of all those forces will still be basically down and to the left. Putting a brace in that direction means the brace will be naturally resisting that force in that same direction, which for such a brace would be tension. If the brace were instead CF, the force would need to climb up to C, where such a mainly-downward force becomes compression for the brace.

So, if all you're looking at is what is best for the brace, BE is the clear winner.

### What's best for the structure?

This one's harder to determine by inspection, but it can still try to apply a bit of intuition. In this case, I find it easier to think about why CF is worse than BE, so let's think about it that way.

I basically explained the problem with a CF brace above, actually. As I said, the force will need to climb all the way up to C before the brace can help out. That already tells us that if the brace is at CF, then CE will suffer a greater load. After all, it'll need to carry the load which a BE brace would have already absorbed.

The fact that there's no brace on E means the entire horizontal force on the right-hand-side will need to be absorbed by EF. If the brace were in BE, it'd be able to absorb some of that horizontal load, making life a bit easier for EF.

After that, it gets a bit tricky to intuit the impact of the brace's orientation. But there's nothing stopping you from running a quick model to see the impact:

[image]

As suspected, a BE brace has tension, and leads to lower forces in CE and EF. However, it leads to much greater compression in BC and causes BF to suffer loads (a CF brace makes BF effectively useless).

So, what's better? A brace under compression which leads to lower compression (or none at all!) in other members but significatly higher tension in others? Or a brace under tension which leads to higher compression in some members but lower tension in others? *A priori* it's a bit ambiguous, especially if you consider the fact that the brace is more susceptible to buckling than the horizontal members (since it's longer) and would be under a greater load.

### Final decision

In this case, I'd probably choose a BE brace: it's better for the brace and at least indifferent for the structure.

---

<sub>Diagram developed with [Ftool](https://www.ftool.com.br/Ftool/), a free educational 2D frame analysis tool.</sub>

Comment: The professor probably set the question for the analysis, so ambiguous is not an issue... Students seem to hate questions where there is "no" right answer (aka all answers are correct) when the analysis is the focus...

Comment: @SolarMike, yeah. It's just that I noticed they bothered mentioning the structure is steel, the use of yield stress, factor of safety... All seemed unnecessary for a purely structural analysis question. And all those terms seemed slightly advanced, so figured buckling would've been at least mentioned and slightly covered by now. But I only now saw the last phrase where they bother defining stress in a truss member. So yeah, maybe this is a more basic course than I'd thought.

Comment: A thorough analysis though... plus 1